# Line styles on gnuplot 4.4

Tags: gnuplot

Well, I'm trying to plot this graphic:

```
gnuplot> plot exp(-x) t 'MB' w l lw 3, (exp(x)-1)**(-1) w l lw 3 t 'BE', (exp(x)+1)**(-1) w l lw 3 t 'FD'
```

and exporting with

```
set terminal latex
```

How, or what, I have to do to the graphics be plotted in different lines styles, as dotted and dashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to specify line styles check the documentation [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-24000043.59.6). You can specify the line type, line color, line width, point type etc.
To specify a blue dotted line on an `X11` terminal do

```
set style line 1 lt 0 lc 3
plot x**2 ls 1
```

Note that the styles also depend on the terminal you are using. To see what possibilities there are use the test page of the current terminal by running `test` in your gnuplot console.

Examples of different line styles can be found [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/misc4-e.html) and [there](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/dashcolor.html).

Comment: Is there any latex based `terminal` (like `latex`, `pstricks`,...) that supports dashed lines?

Comment: @RodrigoThomas I have never used latex terminals. But you can easily check if those terminals have dashed lines using the `test` command.