# gnuplot line type does not want to be changed

Tags: linux, debian, gnuplot

Can you help me please? I want change one line type to dotted. I use these comannds:

```
gnuplot> set terminal png size 750,210 nocrop butt font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf" 8
gnuplot> set output "/root/data.png"
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
gnuplot> set format x "%b %d"
gnuplot> set ylabel "item1"
gnuplot> set y2label "item2"
gnuplot> set y2tics
gnuplot> set datafile separator "|"
gnuplot> plot "/root/results.txt" using 1:2 title "item1" w lines lt 4, "/root/results.txt" using 1:3 title "item2" with lines
```

But I allways get only magenta color line.
I have used Version 4.6 patchlevel 0.
Thanks for replies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8106872/1030675

Comment: @choroba, thanks. But How I set line style in plot drawing syntax please?

Comment: Whats wrong with `plot x lt 4, x**2 lt 3`? But also `plot x lt 4, x**2` should work, but in the second case `linetype 2` is automatically selected.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks. But when I used: 
gnuplot> set style line 1 lt 2 lc 8
gnuplot> set style line 1 lt 1 lc 7
gnuplot> plot "/root/dataASD.txt" using 1:2 title "item1" with lines, "/root/dataASD.txt" using 1:3 title "item2" with lines
I get the same rusult still... Lines are solid, first is red and second is green...

Comment: Yes, because with `set style line` you specify a line *style*, which you select with e.g. `linestyle 1`. By default line *type* is used when nothing is specified.

Comment: Same here.  I can say lw 4 and it works, but lt 2 does not.  I can't seem to draw anything but lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to change the line colors using `set` commands:

1. Define line styles:

   ```
   set style line 1 linetype 1 linecolor 7
   set style line 2 linetype 1 linecolor rgb "#dd7700"
   plot x linestyle 1, x**2 linestyle 2
   ```

   You must explicitely specify which line style is used.
2. Choose and increment over line *style* instead of line *type* if nothing is specified:

   ```
   set style line 1 linetype 1 linecolor 7
   set style line 2 linetype 1 linecolor rgb "#dd7700"
   set style increment user
   plot x, x**2
   ```
3. Redefine the default line *type* (introduced in version 4.6.0):

   ```
   set linetype 1 linecolor 7
   set linetype 2 linetype 1 linecolor rgb "magenta"
   plot x, x**2
   ```

   Beware, that unlike line styles, redefinitions by `set linetype` are persistent;  they are not affected by `reset`. To reset them you must use `set linetype 1 default`.

So a minimal plotting script could look like:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo dashed monochrome
set output "/root/data.png"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%b %d"
set datafile separator "|"
set style data lines

plot "/root/results.txt" using 1:2 linetype 1, "" using 1:3 linetype 3
```

Comment: Thanks. But now how will look my correct plot command please? If I apllied set 1, when I use:
plot "/root/dataASD.txt" linestyle 1 using 1:2 title "item1" with lines, "/root/dataASD.txt" linestyle 2 using 1:3 title "item2" with lines I get error messange: Need full using spec for x time data.

Comment: See the edited answer for a complete script. This should work fine and doesn't change anything about how the time data is handled. Be sure to include a `reset` before executing the code to avoid problems with previous settings in an interactive session.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But second line does not dotted. I set linetype 4. Linetype 4 should be dotted - http://www2.yukawa.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~akira.ohnishi/Lib/gnuplot.html  But I have still solid line. Why please? I need one line dotted, because graph will be print with monochrome print...

Comment: Ups, I sticked to the 'magenta' but haven't noticed the 'dotted' part! You must use the `pngcairo` terminal with the `dashed` option for this, with `png` (i.e. libgd) you can't get dashed lines. Use e.g. `set terminal pngcairo dashed monochrome; set output 'test.png'; plot "/root/results.txt" using 1:2 lt 1 , "" using 1:3 lt 3` to get black, dashed lines, see also [Gnuplot line types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213).

Comment: So If I use:
gnuplot> set terminal pngcairo dashed monochrome
Terminal type set to 'pngcairo'
Options are ' background "#ffffff" fontscale 1.0 monochrome dashed size 640, 480 '
gnuplot> set output 'bodkaD1.png'
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
gnuplot> set format x "%b %d"
gnuplot> set datafile separator "|"
gnuplot> plot "/root/dataASD.txt" using 1:2 title "item1" lt 1, "/root/dataASD.txt" using 1:3 title "item2" lt 3
I get graph from scattered plus and stars symbols.

Comment: I need graph with line, that will be for example from stras symbols... In your picture for example lien 17...

Comment: Thats what `set style data lines` is for, or use `with lines` after plotting. Please use the *complete* script at the end of the answer, thats why I posted it!

Answer (score 0):

On the X-11 terminal I have no trouble changing the line color but have had no success changing line types to include dotted and/or dashed lines.

Comment: With gnuplot 5 you must use `dashtype` to get dashed or dotted lines, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28438812/2604213 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/29950759/2604213 for actual examples and explanations of it syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I see what they are saying.  Will test it out.  Upvote for your comment.