# How to produce dashed lines in gnuplot 5 using TikZ terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

I have recently upgraded to gnuplot 5 and have been unable to produce dashed lines using the TikZ terminal. Running these commands:

```
set term tikz
set output "test.tex"
test
```

produce dashed line types in gnuplot 4.6 (first image), but only solid ones in gnuplot 5 (second image). Is there a way to fix this without downgrading?

I have tried setting different values for the `dashlength` terminal option, but that didn't help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With 5.0 gnuplot has changed its way to deal with dashed lines. All line types are solid by default, this is what the `test` command shows you.

To enable dashed lines, use the new `dashtype` keyword, e.g

```
plot for [i=1:4] i*x dashtype i
```

That works for all terminals which support dashed lines.

Note, that with `dashtype` you can also specify your own dash patterns.

Example script:

```
set terminal lua tikz linewidth 3 standalone
set output 'dash.tex'    
unset key

set linetype 1 dashtype 2
set linetype 2 dashtype '..-'
set linetype 3 dashtype (2,2,4,4,6,6)
plot for [i=1:3] i*x
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason, why it must be done this way (it doesn't work for me:( )

Comment: @V-X What exactly do you mean? It works like it works ;) Which terminal do you use? Note, that not all terminal support dashed lines at all.