# Dotted horizontal lines in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, line

I am using something like

```
set arrow 1 from 0,-0.5 to 3,-0.5 nohead
```

to draw vertical or horizontal lines.

How can I create dotted/dashed lines though?

Related [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2622293) the following linetype works

```
set arrow 1 from 0,-0.5 to 3,-0.5 nohead lt 0
```

but e.g. `lt 3` doesn't.

Comment: I would try something like `set arrow 1 from 0,-0.5 to 3,-0.5 nohead dt "."`, i.e., to specify the `dashtype` instead of `linetype` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/5351549

Comment: Additionally, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28438812/2604213 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/29950759/2604213 for more information about `dashtype`

Comment: I am using Gnuplot `Version 4.6 patchlevel 2`. Is it possible for that version too or do I have to upgrade to version 5?

Comment: `lt 2` or `lt 3` doesn't work? Does it display a line at all? What terminal are you using? Try using an alternate terminal for testing

Comment: @GavinPortwood It displays a line but this is not dotted. I tried png terminal which changes nothing. By default I am using `x11`.

Comment: Please try something a terminal other than `png` or `x11`. `pngcairo` would be good if you have it (check with `set term`). There are issues with the `png` terminal with `linestyles` on some versions.  You can use dashed `linestyles` in X11 but must set them in ~/.Xdefaults (see [this](http://wiki.octave.org/Enable_%22linestyle%22_functionality_for_Gnuplot%27s_x11_terminal) or `help set term x11 line`)