# Exact meaning of dashtype index in the Gnuplot 5.0?

Tags: gnuplot

I got a problem in Gnuplot 5.0, the dashtype index, such as ``set dashtype 1 (2,5,2,15)` in the manual.

My question is: what do these numbers in parenthesis exactly mean? I tried to change them to get a feeling, but it would be great to know the exact meaning.

My actual problem is, that simply using `dashtype N`, gives lines which look very different from the previous 4.6 version, unfortunately. I just try to reproduce the plots which were made in gnuplot 4.6.

Comment: What have you looked at to try to determine this?

Comment: Actually quite simple. I just try to reproduce my plots which were made with gnuplot 4.6. It seems a pity that the upgrade has not kept the default the same as v4.6. I mean, the default "dashtype 1" in v5.0 is not the same style as "linetye 1" in v4.6. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Those are numerical pairs

```
<solid length>,<empty length>
```

Those lengths are factors for an internal unit length. The dash pattern length further depends on the `dashlength` terminal option and the line width.

So, having

```
plot x dt (2,4,2,6)
```

plots a dash, an empty space twice as long, again a dash of same length and an empty space three times the dash length.

The actual length of the first dash is then

```
linewidth * terminal_linewidth * solid_length * terminal_dashlength * dash_unit
```

First example:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 600,50 dashlength 2 linewidth 1
set output 'dash1.png'
unset border; unset key; unset tics
plot 0 dt (2,4,2,6) lw 10
```

[image]

What might be confusing is, that some terminals like `qt` or `wxt` use rounded line ends by default (terminal option `round`), which are applied to every single dash, which distorts the actually given dash lengths:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 600,50 round dashlength 2 linewidth 1
set output 'dash2.png'
unset border; unset key; unset tics
plot 0 dt (2,4,2,6) lw 10
```

[image]

Terminal option `square` extends each dash by one line width at each end:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 600,50 square dashlength 2 linewidth 1
set output 'dash2.png'
unset border; unset key; unset tics
plot 0 dt (2,4,2,6) lw 10
```

[image]

In this last example, the final dash lengths are (4,2,4,4).

To get the behavior of the first example (exact dash length) also by default with other terminals, use the `butt` terminal option.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. actually I could imagine what you said before I asked the question. However, what I am really need is something like a formula which I failed to find. Moreover, I am still not clear what exactly the first and third numbers mean. It is confusing and looks strange for me if they stands for number of solid line and empty space.

Answer (score 1):

from: http://www.gnuplot.info/gnuplot_cvs.pdf page 37

```
set dashtype 1 (2,5,2,15)
```

means: define stype 1 as:

```
solid 2
empty 5
solid 2
empty 15

(==     ==               )*
```

Comment: Sorry, I still do not know what does each of them really mean. Does the number 2 mean double lines? I tried, it does not show like this...