# Setting linewidth and dashtype in Gnuplot 5.0

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a dashed line with a thickness of 2 in Gnuplot 5.0 in the epslatex terminal. In previous versions I could have accomplished this with something like the following:

```
plot 'datafile' u 1:2 w l lt 2 lw 2
```

In 5.0, `lt` doesn't change the dashtype by default. If I try something similar such as

```
plot 'datafile' u 1:2 w l dt 2 lw 2
```

then I will get a dashed line of thickness 1. If in the above expression I change the dashtype to `dt 1` (a solid line), then the thickness will be 2 as I want. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That is a bug, see http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1600/ Try `dt 2 lw 4`. Note, that in version 5 the dash patterns scale with the linewidth, so maybe you want to set a custom dash pattern like `dt (1 0.5)`.

Comment: @Christoph, Thanks. The first suggestion pretty much solves my problem, except that because of the scaling of the patterns (I think), it is hard to distinguish the different patterns from each other. I tried your second suggestion, but any use of that syntax produces a solid line of various thickness. I mean that I use `dt (n,scale)`, where `n` is an integer not equal to 1 and `scale` is some decimal number.

Comment: The meaning of these numbers is different, maybe you need larger values like `dt (2 3)` to see it. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29950759/2604213 for a detailed explanation of the dash type syntax